# Can I retrieve an ipad unique device identifier that through Safari with a js web app?

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari, udid

We have an application running on a Windows Server and being accessed by IPads from Safari. The web part is written in javascript.

We would like to store user preferences in the server, but are lacking an identifying number that we can retrieve from the ipad device through our web code, so as to store different ipad's settings under different folders. We have still not implemented user profiles.

I've been doing some reading about the UDID and haven't found a way to retrieve this number with javascript. Is it possible? Is there any other device number or kind of ID that we could use for this purpose?

Thank you!

Comment: This combined with that AT&T leak where they had a completely open web service that allowed you to retrieve the email addresses of iPad owners based on a simple query using the UDID and, well, there goes ALL pretense to privacy..

Answer (score 1):

I would think this is a very bad idea(tm).

Instead, why not just do what everyone else does and store your own generated ID in a cookie that pretty much never expires?