# How to get iPhone's Unique Identifier (UDID) using iwebkit?

Tags: iphone, udid, iwebkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I retrieve an ipad unique device identifier that through Safari with a js web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764115/can-i-retrieve-an-ipad-unique-device-identifier-that-through-safari-with-a-js-we)
>   [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

How to get iPhone's Unique Identifier (UDID) using iwebkit...any code?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's not possible and if it is than it should be bug.

// Following work around(reference) may help you.. //

http://whatismyudid.com/

Hope, this may help you..

Comment: Can anybody tell me why i got down vote..? There is no personal but i want to know my mistake. Please tell me.

Comment: Probably because your code was ObjC and the OP wanted the UDID via WebKit. Just a wild guess, though.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez : I don't think so. Because i have i already mention that following code is for iPhone.

Comment: UniqueIdentifier is deprecated.